# Regular expression to match decimals with or without trailing zeros

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression for accepting floats with 2 decimals:

```
[0-9]*.[0-9]{2}$
```

How do I change this so the expression accepts 7 without having to enter 7.00?

Would this work?

```
[0-9]*.[0-9]{0,1,2}$
```

Does it still then require the decimal point? i.e. 7.00

Comment: Try [`[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?`](https://regex101.com/r/tG0yK5/1) If you need upto two decimal points, use `[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?`

Comment: Might be OP need it to be upto two decimal points like as `[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{0,2})?` @Tushar

Answer (score 0):

You can make part of the regex optional by surrounding it with parenthesis `()` and `?` like so:

```
(optional regex)?
```

So do

```
[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2})?$
```